# Change button icon on click

Tags: angular

I'm trying to change the icon and the functionality of a button upon logging/logging out. I wrote the following code:

**navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/app/services/authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public loggedIn; 

  constructor(private authService : AuthenticationService, private router : Router) { 
    this.loggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn(); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  logOut(){
    this.authService.logout() 
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span>SB Betting</span>

        <span class="example-spacer"></span>
        <button *ngIf="!loggedIn" mat-icon-button [routerLink]="'/login'">
            <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Login">exit_to_app</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button *ngIf="loggedIn" mat-icon-button [routerLink]="'/'" (click)="logOut()">
            <mat-icon class="example-icon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Logout">settings_power</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Upon clicking one of the buttons the icon/functionality is not changed in the navbar, the user is logged in/logged out when clicking and after refreshing the correct icon is loaded. How can I achieve this without reloading the page? I also tried putting the `this.loggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn();` in the `ngInit` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-assign variable when you click after logout. This will change your button.

```
this.loggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
```

For Updating Navigation from LoginComponent you required to do component interaction. You need to have one service which is injected in both component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonServiceService {

  private loginDone= new BehaviorSubject<boolean>();
  loginDoneObservable$ = this.loginDone.asObservable(); 

  constructor() { }

  loginDone(status){
    this.loginDone.next(status);
  }
}
```

Now from your Login component you need to do as per below.

```
this._commonServices.loginDone(true);
```

In your NavigationComponent you need to subscribe for observable in service.

```
this._commonServices.loginDoneObservable$
    .subscribe(
        #Update your login variable here.
    )
}
```

Comment: That only works for logging out, logging in doesn't change the icon, probably because logging in is a different component which doesn't have the loggedIn var. How to deal with that?

Comment: There you need to do component interaction. Try to read example from here and you will understand. http://shabbirdhangot.com/angular-8-component-interaction-using-service/